# In which file do you set nuget packages for a .NET Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I found something called "MyProjectName.deps.json" in the "bin" directory. But if i delete the "bin" directory and build my project again it gets created again. Where does VisualStudio pull this data from (which packages should be included in the project)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based upon the `obj\project.assets.json` file (generated by NuGet restore) which defines inputs to the build logic that are used for the generation of the `.deps.json` file, along with other references from the project file.

Comment: But if i delete the whole "obj" and "bin" directory. Where does the "dotnet restore" get the package information from?

Comment: that's from the `PackageReference` and `ProjecReference` items in the project file

Comment: Oh my... Thanks. They indeed are in the .csproj file under "<ItemGroup> --> <PackageReference>". I was checking the .csproj file of another project. That's why i couldn't find it. :D